# Passing a PHP variable using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to pass a php variable from page1.html (which contains a php variable that I got from another form) to page2.php using ajax but it's not working, so I need your help.

code from page1.php:

```
<script>
var url = 'page2.php';
$("#save").click( function() {
    $.ajax({
        url : url,
        type: 'post',
        data : {
            admin : <?php echo $admin; ?>,
            gname : <?php echo $gname; ?>,
            filename : docname,
            content : encodeURIComponent(editor.getValue())
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

The datas `filename` and `content` are being sent successfully but `admin` and `gname` are not.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['admin'])) {
    $admin = $_GET['admin'];
    }
    if(isset($_GET['gname'])) {
    $gname = $_GET['gname'];
    }
?>
```

This code is where I get the php variable that I want to send, from another form which is **irrelevant** to this question.

Answer (score 3):

Here you go buddy, replace your script code with this.

```
<script>
var url = 'page2.php';
var admin = '<?php echo $admin; ?>';
var gname = '<?php echo $gname; ?>';
$("#save").click( function() {
    $.ajax({
        url : url,
        type: 'post',
        data : {
            admin : admin,
            gname : gname,
            filename : docname,
            content : encodeURIComponent(editor.getValue())
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Youre using the type `post` so must use the `$_POST` in php

**PHP**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['admin'])) {
    $admin = $_POST['admin'];
    }
    if(isset($_POST['gname'])) {
    $gname = $_POST['gname'];
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `$_GET['admin']` which is used to fetch parameters delivered with GET method. You should be using `$_POST['admin']` since you have set POST as your http request type in the JS code.

Comment: NO, all the code above is in page1.php. The ajax will send the data to page2.php  where I use $_POST['admin']. I'm using $_GET['admin'] to get the data that I want to send.

Comment: You can try alert to see whether you are getting value of admin variable or not.

Comment: @hrs I know its not being sent. I just want to know why is it not working.

Comment: Before starting AJAX, below var url; define new variable.
var admin = '<?php echo $admin; ?>';
and then alert the admin.

Comment: @hrs The alert worked and displayed the variable, but its still not sending.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone is saying you're mixing POST and GET. But it caught another thing that may bother you. Are those variables strings? If they are, maybe you're missing the apostrophe/single quote.

```
<script>
var url = 'page2.php';
$("#save").click( function() {
$.ajax({
   url : url,
    type: 'post',
    data : {
        admin : '<?php echo $admin; ?>',
        gname : '<?php echo $gname; ?>',
        filename : docname,
        content : encodeURIComponent(editor.getValue())
    }
});
});
</script>>
```

Comment: If the "page1.html" is html, it's impossible to get the php variables. Is the page1, the one that creating the javascript code, a php or html?

Comment: it's php. The variable working and displaying on page1.php but its not being sent to page2.php for some reason.

Comment: Ok. just making sure. I would recommend you to use some tool, like firebug to make sure that variables are being sent. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Your below code

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['admin'])) {
    $admin = $_GET['admin'];
    }
    if(isset($_GET['gname'])) {
    $gname = $_GET['gname'];
    }
?>
```

is to be replaced by

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['admin'])) {
    $admin = $_POST['admin'];
    }
    if(isset($_POST['gname'])) {
    $gname = $_POST['gname'];
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are sending POST parameters,while using get in PHP script. And another issue is you are not using quotes with **$admin** and **$gname** variables in ajax request.
Try following :

```
<script>
var url = 'page2.php';
$("#save").click( function() {
    $.ajax({
        url : url,
        type: 'post',
        data : {
            admin : '<?php echo $admin; ?>',
            gname : '<?php echo $gname; ?>',
            filename : docname,
            content : encodeURIComponent(editor.getValue())

        }
    });
});
</script>
```

**PHP Script:**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['admin'])) {
        $admin = $_POST['admin'];
    }
    if(isset($_POST['gname'])) {
        $gname = $_POST['gname'];
    }
?>
```

Check if it helps you.